# Crash while detecting rectangles, Swift, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, rectangles

I am trying to detedct rectangles with vision. every so often i get a crash with this explination.

> Assertion failed: (maxDev != -1.f), function straightLineWLSQ, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Vision/Vision-1.5.3/RectangleDetector/QuadDetect/Leq.c, line 217.

Here is the function that crashes.

```
func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {


    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        do {

            let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
            // This is where I get the error.
            try imageRequestHandler.perform(
                [VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:{ req, err in
                    self.rectanglesRequest(request:req, error:err)

                })]
            )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.sliceCompletion(UIImage())
            print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We are also facing same issue in our project. Did you find any solutions ?

Comment: Im not to sure it’s been a while since I worked on it.

Comment: Thank you response.

Answer (score 0):

Same issues have faced on my project and solved by skipping some image like ImageWidth too higher than ImageHeight and ImageHeight too higher than ImageWidth.

Crash will be happen when we try to detect rectangle of some image like **(ImageWidth:1240,ImageHeight:121**) or **(ImageWidth:121,ImageHeight:1240)**

```
func performVisionRequest(image: CGImage, orientation: CGImagePropertyOrientation) {


       let ratioW = image.width / image.height
       let ratioH = image.height / image.width

       if(ratio < 7) //To skip crash image
       {
           DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {

             do {

                   let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
            // This is where I get the error.
                   try imageRequestHandler.perform(
                [VNDetectRectanglesRequest(completionHandler:{ req, err in
                    self.rectanglesRequest(request:req, error:err)

                })]
            )
        } catch let error as NSError {
            self.sliceCompletion(UIImage())
            print("Failed to perform vision request: \(error)")

        }
    }
  }
}
```